# how to download the files and folder from antifactory using script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, artifactory

I am new with python . I want to download the all files and with there corresponding folder from antifactory link which will provide from us can anyone help me for solving this issue .

Comment: i need the script for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveFolderorRepositoryArchive) to download the complete folder and archive it.